# Regression with unlabeled data from several clusters

Tags: regression, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I want to characterize the relation of a few input parameters to a single output parameter. The problem I have is that my data is collected from several groups. The groups are defined both by the input parameters and by how the input parameters interact with the output parameter. I don't know the identity or proportion of each group in the data.

**Example**: I want to characterize how ear and tail lengths are related to maximal vertical jump height and my data has for each surveyed animal the value of these three parameters. Unbeknownst to me, the data was collected from:

1. *bunnies*, whose maximal jump height is proportional to the length of their ears.
2. *striped cats* whose maximal jump is proportional to the length of their tail.
3. *dotted cats* whose maximal jump is inversely proportional to the length of their tail.

Regressing the whole group together would not identify the true effects in the data. I could first  cluster the data on the input parameters (e.g. with k-means) but then miss groups that share similar input features while interact differently with the output feature (striped and dotted cats).

A non-efficient solution could be to consider different partitions of the data and give each data partitioning some score integrating the cluster quality (e.g. within cluster similarity and between cluster dissimilarity) with the regression accuracy (e.g. sum of squares of the residuals). The problem is that there are a lot of ways to partition the data.

I wonder whether there is a more **systematic way to integrate the clustering and regression** processes.

Comment: You may want to look at latent class analysis as a clustering tool.